# Subclipse not adding new files to version control

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, subclipse

Eclipse Maven WAR project is not automatically adding new files to version control. What could it be?

Here are some information:

1. Both Eclipse Mars.2 and Neon present the same problem
2. Using latest version of Subclipse (1.10.13) with SVN Kit interface
3. All developers have the same problem
4. JAR Maven projects do not present the problem, only WAR type
5. Changes to versioned files are working ok, only new files present the problem
6. Already tried new installation, didn't work
7. Checked Eclipse logs and there is nothing suggesting the cause

As the image shows, a new file created was not added to version control:

[image]

Comment: Maybe because it is listed in `.svnignore`? Also, the screenshot doesn't show that the rest of the files are version-controlled.

Comment: Side note: if you have a choice (and you are running Linux), consider using **git svn** instead of svn. To you, git-svn looks like git (with all the features of git), but towards the repository, it is still "talking SVN". Meaning: you can use git, you don't need subclipse, or any other of those half-broken-always-slow SVN solutions ... and nobody else needs to know. And all of a sudden, all such problems ... are gone. I found that to be an enormous "time saver" for me.

Comment: @GhostCat Hum that is unrelated to the question at hand and really your opinions there. I used Subclipse for a long time and never encountered any issues or performance problems. Comments are not the place for Git vs SVN wars.

Comment: @Tunaki The extension .TXT is not ignored. Other files are .java, .xml, .wsdl.

Comment: @Tunaki I too have used for many years, pretty good plugin, just can't figure why it is behaving that way for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went to repository perspective, right-clicked the project directory, properties. Found attribute svn:global-ignores = *

No idea why it is there but removing it will let the client version new files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! You can also do that from the Package Explorer or Navigator view: right click the project and from the context menu select Team > Show properties.